# Spell Checker with Web Browser control in .NET application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement Spell checker functionality in my application.
Is this possible with web browser control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this hyperlink and then implement your own logic to do underline in web browser.

http://www.maierhofer.de/en/documentation/nhunspell/index.html

This is open source spell checker.

Comment: anything for Textcontrol? :P

Comment: No open source spell checker is available for that. You have to use tx spell checker for that.. :(